# Accessing contents of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I need to access the contents of a vector. The vector contains a structure and I need to loop through the vector and access the structure members.

How can I do that using a for loop and the vector iterator?

Comment: More details please. What data types are your using?

Comment: what's wrong with vec[i]? , meaning - the [] operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use iterators or `[]`:

```
// assuming vector will store this type:
struct Stored {
    int Member;
};

//and will be declared like this:
std::vector<Stored> vec;

// here's how the traversal loop looks like with iterators
for( vector<Stored >::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++ ) {
   it->Member;
}

// here's how it looks with []
for( std::vector<Stored>::size_type index = 0; index < vec.size(); index++ ) {
   vec[index].Member;
}
```

Comment: With a new compiler that supports the new C++11 standard (like VS2010 or gcc 4.4 (at least)) it's even less to write: `for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)`.

Comment: now I need to access only certain members of the vector. I need the index of the vector contents. and only if I find the required index I will read the structure member. how do I do that ? Because the for loop uses .begin() and .end()

Comment: @user1039630: Updated, added another version that uses indices

Comment: How to do the same thing using std::foreach ?

Answer (score 2):

All STL containers provide an common interface called **Iterators** to access the contents of the STL container. The advantage here is if you need to change the STL container at a later point(You find that particular container does not suit your requirement and want to change to a new container) of time,Your code is much more loosely coupled, as the Iterator interface will not change.

**[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/HhXjm)**:

```
    #include<iostream>     
    #include<string>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    struct Student
    {
        string lastName;
        string firstName;
    };

    int main()
    {
        Student obj;
        obj.firstName = "ABC";
        obj.lastName = "XYZ";

        vector<Student> students;
        students.push_back(obj);
        vector<Student>::iterator it;

        cout << "students contains:";
        for ( it=students.begin() ; it != students.end(); ++it )
        {
            cout << " " << (*it).firstName;
            cout << " " << (*it).lastName;
        }

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Assume vector contains 100 students. Now I want to access only the 1st , 10th, 79th student's first and last name. how can I do that?

Comment: @user1039630: You fill the vector using `vector::push_back()` or `vector::insert()` methods and once the vector is filled with elements, you can access\modify those elements using the `[]` operator. Note that you need to check the index of `[]` is valid by checking `vector::size()` or it will result in Undefined Behavior.